# convert an word number to numaric equivalent

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a American word number to number after extracting from an string.I have given a try here http://jsfiddle.net/golupant/fT2tk/

i.e **I want to convert ten thousand four hundred forty to its numeric equivalent -- 10440.**

```
function word2numberConverter ( wordNumber) {

    wordNumber = wordNumber.toLowerCase();
    //different notations under hundred
    var underTen = {
        'zero': 0,      'one': 1,       'two': 2,       'three': 3,     'four': 4,      'five': 5,           'six': 6,      'seven': 7,     'eight': 8,     'nine': 9
    };
    var underHundred = {
        'ten': 10,      'eleven': 11,       'twelve': 12,   'thirteen': 13,
        'fourteen': 14,     'fifteen': 15,  'sixteen': 16,      'seventeen': 17,    'eighteen': 18,     'nineteen': 19, 'twenty': 20,
        'thirty': 30,       'forty': 40,    'fifty': 50,        'sixty': 60,    'seventy': 70,      'eighty': 80,   'ninety': 90
        };

    //different magnitude each after the increament 10 pow 3
    var magnitude = {
        'thousand': '10^3', 'million':'10^6',       'billion':'10^9',       'trillion':'10^12',     'quadrillion':'10^15',
        'quintillion':'10^18',  'sextillion':'10^21',       'septillion':'10^24',   'octillion':'10^27',        'nonillion':'10^30',
        'decillion':'10^33',    'undecillion':'10^36',      'duodecillion':'10^39', 'tredecillion':'10^42',     'quattuordecillion':'10^45',
        'quindecillion':'10^48','sexdecillion':'10^51',     'septendecillion':'10^54',  'octadecillion':'10^57',    'novemdecillion':'10^60',
        'vigintillion':'10^63',
        };

    //window.console&&console.log(wordNumber);
    var wordnumElements = wordNumber.split(/[\s-]+/); 
    //alert('++++'+wordnumElements);
    var num = 0;
    var tempnum = 0;
    var isUnderHundred = 0;
    var isHundred = 0;
    var isMagnitude = 0;
    var isUnderTen = 0;
    var isValidNum = 1;
    var element = '';
    var wordnumElementsLength = wordnumElements.length;
    for (var i=0;i < wordnumElementsLength; i++) {
        element = wordnumElements[i];
        window.console&&console.log(element);
        //wordnumElements.forEach(function( element ) {
        if(!isValidNum) {
            //if invalid number then return
            break;
        }
        var temp = underTen[element];
        if(temp != null) {
            if(isUnderTen) {
                //can't be a valid number
                isValidNum = 0;
            } else {
                tempnum = tempnum + temp;
                isUnderTen =1;
                //reset isHundred , isUnderHundred and isMagnitude
                isHundred = 0;
                isUnderHundred = 0;
                isMAgnitude = 0;
            }
        } else {    
            var temp = underHundred[element];
            if(temp != null) {
                if(isUnderHundred){
                    //can't be a valid number
                    isValidNum = 0;
                } else {
                    tempnum = tempnum + temp;
                    isUnderHundred = 1;
                    //reset isHundred , isUnderTen and isMagnitude
                    isUnderTen = 0;
                    isHundred = 0;
                    isMagnitude = 0;
                }                
             } else {
                if ( element == "hundred" ) {

                    if(isHundred || isUnderHundred) {  // there can never be underHundred string before valid american wordnumber like one thousand forty hundred is invalid
                        //not a valid number
                        isValidNum = 0;
                    } else {
                        isHundred =1;
                        //reset underHundred and isMagnitude
                        isUnderHundred = 0;
                        isMagnitude = 0;
                        isUnderTen = 0;
                    }
                    if(!tempnum) {    // to give support for one thousand hundred forty as 1140
                        tempnum = 1;
                    }
                    tempnum = tempnum *100;

                } else {
                    temp = magnitude[element];
                    if(temp ){
                        if(isMagnitude == 1) {
                            //not a valid number
                            isValidNum = 0;
                        } else {
                            isMagnitude = 1;
                            //reset isUnderHundred and isHundred
                            isUnderHundred = 0;
                            isHundred = 0;
                            isUnderTen = 0;
                        }
                        var val = temp.split(/\^/);
                        temp = Math.pow(val[0],val[1]);

                        window.console&&console.log('num--'+num);
                        window.console&&console.log('tempnum--'+tempnum);
                        window.console&&console.log('temp--'+temp)
                        if( temp != null) {
                            if(num && isMagnitude && temp > num) {
                                window.console&&console.log('i m --> num * temp + tempnum===>'+num+'--'+temp+'--'+tempnum);
                                num = (num  + tempnum)* temp;
                            } else {
                                window.console&&console.log('i m addition--> num + tempnum * temp===>'+num+'--'+tempnum+'--'+temp);
                                num = num + tempnum * temp;
                            }
                            tempnum = 0;
                        } else {
                            isValidWordNum = 0;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }

        window.console&&console.log('enum--'+num);
        window.console&&console.log('etempnum--'+tempnum);
        window.console&&console.log('etemp--'+temp);
    }
    num = num + tempnum;
    alert("final num-"+num);
    if(!isValidNum) {
        return wordNumber;
    } else {
        return num;
    }    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/golupant/LFrm7/12/ -- works perfectly if number gose downword. mean the highest magnitude come at the first place then smaller ...

In http://jsfiddle.net/golupant/fT2tk/  I have tried to take care of numbers like

> "two hundred five million forty billion one thousand seven hundred
>   fifty"

I is working till some extant but not fully correct. **I just want to do like google does**.

Please do google "two hundred five million forty billion one thousand seven hundred fifty -1". You will come to know what I want.

Can somebody help me out to do this? Although I want in javascript but I am OK in other language too.

Comment: No one would write a number like *"two hundred five million forty billion one thousand seven hundred fifty"* because it's not correct. Does your function really need to handle this bizarre case?

Comment: @yuck-- Please try at google as i mentioned.
https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=equailent#q=two+hundred+five+million+forty+billion+one+thousand+seven+hundred+fifty+-1

Comment: just tried your link, but it seems the number in the calculator is wrong

Comment: Great ..! You are saying that there is bug in google calculator. But I am not agree with you.Its correct.Can you give some reference to foster your statement.

Comment: There are several node.js libraries that do this. Check out `wordy` and `text2num` on npm or github and see how they do it (or better, just use them). There's even `readint` which can handle English, French, Spanish and German. They all have zero dependencies on other libraries so should be simple to port to the browser if necessary.

Comment: @slebetman -- I am really very sorry. Can you please provide link. I checked at github but I could not get. I got library very easily to convert a number to word but not from word to number.